# Проблемы с классом Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

Tags: php

Проблема состоит в том, что мне нужно выгрузить большой объем данных. Если убрать `For`, то файл формируется нормально, если вернуть данные которые идут в `For`'e, то файл гененрируется с ошибкой. Если уменьшить кол-во записей до 5, то все ок. Скажите, в чем проблема в памяти? Её достаточно, может где то я параметр пропустил?

```
$xls =& new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();
$xls->setVersion(8);
$worksheet =& $xls->addWorksheet('List');

$worksheet->setInputEncoding('utf-8');

$upper_left_side_brick = $xls->addFormat();
$upper_left_side_brick->setLeft(1);
$upper_left_side_brick->setRight(1);
$upper_left_side_brick->setTop(1);
$upper_left_side_brick->setBottom(1);
$upper_left_side_brick->setSize(12);
$upper_left_side_brick->setPattern(1);
$upper_left_side_brick->setBorderColor('black');
$upper_left_side_brick->setFgColor('white');
$upper_left_side_brick->setAlign('centre');
$worksheet->setColumn(0, 5, strlen("Название товара"));
$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Категория', $upper_left_side_brick);
$worksheet->write(0, 1, 'Название товара', $upper_left_side_brick);
$worksheet->write(0, 2, 'Описание товара', $upper_left_side_brick);
$worksheet->write(0, 3, 'Ссылка', $upper_left_side_brick);
$worksheet->write(0, 4, 'Бренд', $upper_left_side_brick);
$worksheet->write(0, 5, 'Цена', $upper_left_side_brick);

$upper_left_side_brick->setAlign('right');

if ($object) {
$i = 1;
foreach ($object as $obj) {

    $tree  = Model::getMothers($obj['id'], 66);
    $dtree = array();
    foreach ($tree as $t) {

        $dtree[] = $t['name'];

    }

    $worksheet->write($i, 0, join(" > ", $dtree), $upper_left_side_brick);
    $worksheet->write($i, 1, $obj['Название'], $upper_left_side_brick);
    $worksheet->write($i, 2, strip_tags($obj['Описание']),$upper_left_side_brick);
    $worksheet->write($i, 3, 'http://localhost/' . Core::$_lang . '/goods/show/' . Helpers::hurl_encode($obj['id'], $obj['Название']) . '', $upper_left_side_brick);
    $worksheet->write($i, 4, Model::getObject($obj['Бренд'], TRUE)->field("Заголовок"), $upper_left_side_brick);
    $worksheet->write($i, 5, $obj['Цена'], $upper_left_side_brick);
    $i++;
    if ($i == 50) {
        break;
    }

    }
}
$xls->send(date("d-m-Y") . "-ext.xls");
$xls->close();
```

Comment: "Если убрать For" - поясните пожалуйсто что вы этим хотели сказать. И второй вопрос - сколько записей выгружаете в каждый лист?

Comment: Проблема решилась тем что (не знаю с чем это связано) всю работу класса я вынес за пределы ООП то есть запускал отдельно не в классах.

Answer (score 1):

Я сталкивался с подобной проблемой. `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer()` - это старый класс и при работе с большими объемами данных ему не хватает памяти. Как это исправить? -Да никак. Разве что переписать сам `Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer()` =). Более того, я пытался использовать и другие классы, связывающие `php` и `excel`, но все равно столкнулся с тем же самым. Видимо, они используют одни и те же библиотеки.

Попробуйте разбить лист эксель на более мелкие части. Я уже плохо помню точную цифру, но у меня проблемы начались, когда в листе более становилось 8000-10000 строк или около того.